# Remove default mark in choice box

Tags: css, javafx

I created my own mark to check items in a choicebox but when I pass over the option chosen the default shape appears again, how I can remove it?

```
.choice-box{
     -fx-mark-color: transparent; /* OK */
}

.choice-box > .context-menu > .menu-item:checked > .left-container{
     -fx-background-image: url('myMark.png'); /* OK */
     -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;        /* OK */     
}

.choice-box > .context-menu > .menu-item:checked:hover > .left-container{           
     -fx-background-color: red; /* OK */
}

.choice-box > .context-menu > .menu-item:checked:hover > .left-container > .mark{           
     -fx-background-color: transparent; /* Not work */
     -fx-shape: none;                   /* Not work */ 
}     

.choice-box > .context-menu > .menu-item:checked:hover > .left-container > .check{           
     -fx-background-color: transparent; /* Not work */
     -fx-shape: none;                   /* Not work */    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to access to the label's mark is with `-fx-focused-mark-color`, so the full code is:

```
.choice-box{
     -fx-mark-color: transparent; /* OK */
     -fx-focused-mark-color: transparent; /* The solution! */
}

.choice-box > .context-menu > .menu-item:checked > .left-container{
     -fx-background-image: url('myMark.png'); /* OK */
     -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;        /* OK */     
}

.choice-box > .context-menu > .menu-item:checked:hover > .left-container{           
     -fx-background-color: red; /* OK */
}
```

Comment: From where you learnt/got this class? .left-container ? I'm unable to find it in `caspian.css` and `modena.css`